# creating an activity stream (news feed) view in android

Tags: java, android, instagram, activity-streams

I have been working on creating a social networking application. Now am battling with effectively implementing the activity stream view. This is what I have done so far a feed (view) with only a user post (thats only text display) and [a feed (view) with an image and user post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw0lp.png). Now I have a demand to implement a feed with multiple images just like [facebook example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvMAP.png). I have series of questions about what am doing.

Firstly, how do I achieve that facebook example? Displaying multiple images with the user's post (Must not necessary be four, something like when the user uploads more than one image at least few of them show and an indication that there are still other images not displaying). Any logic is welcome, not necessary the codes.

Secondly, I need a way to build a custom view for handling a user post of only text, text + image, only image, only video, text + image + video, etc at once. This custom view should be able parse data from database and handle accordingly. I will so much appreciate ideas on how to go about it.

Any available library is also welcome.

Comment: For the card layout part you can use the [cards](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-usage)

Comment: @Murat K. you mean the second question?

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, i found a library for it called AsymmetricGridView in github https://github.com/felipecsl/AsymmetricGridView